# $|a|−|b|$ is less than or equal to $|a−b|$

Tags: absolute-value

Prove: $|a|−|b|$ is less than or equal to $a−b|$

I sloved this problem by assuming it was right, than checking if $a-b>0$, $a$ positive\negative b$$ positive\negative than doing the same thing with $a-b<0$.

I have a feeling it has a more simple way

Comment: $$(|a|-|b|)^2-a^2-b^2=-2|ab|\le-2ab=|a-b|^2-a^2-b^2$$

Comment: I don't think beginning by assuming the desired result makes for a convincing proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $|a| = |b + (a-b)| \le |a-b| + ?$

Comment: Perhaps write it in the reverse order: $|(a-b)+b|$. It is clearer that way.

Comment: Thanks, its indeed solved it,

Answer (score 0):

We can prove a stronger result, called the ["reverse triangle inequality"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality):
$$
\bigl||a|-|b|\bigr|\le |a-b| \, .
$$
The regular triangle inequality states that $|a+b|\le|a|+|b|$:

- If we replace $a$ with $a-b$, the triangle inequality becomes $|a|\le|a-b|+|b|$. So $|a|-|b|\le|a-b|$, which is the result you wanted to prove.
- If we replace $b$ with $b-a$, the triangle inequality becomes $|b|\le|a|+|b-a|$, so $|b|-|a|\le|b-a|=|a-b|$.

Now what can you conclude by combining the results $|a|-|b|\le|a-b|$, and $|b|-|a|\le|a-b|$?